# In Word, how can I alter mail merge data programmatically with VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-field, fieldcodes

I have a Word document that is used as the source document for a mail merge.  I can edit the document, but not the data being used for the merge.  I need to transform some of the data in the data source (specifically, I need to take numbers (e.g. 342) and add their value in words (e.g. "three hundred forty-two (342)")).  I can write a VBA function to do the transformation, but I'm not sure how best to get the data to that function.

Is there some way I can associate a macro with specific points in the document and let the merging drive the transformation process?  (I'm thinking of how you can use formulas in Word fields; I have a few things of the form **`{ IF { MERGEFIELD foo } > 75 { MERGEFIELD foo } { = { MERGEFIELD foo } * 20 } }`** in the document already.  If I could add something so I could go **`{ FUNCTION WordNum { MERGEFIELD number } }`**, that would be ideal.)

Alternately, I think I can use VBA to rummage around in the mail merge's datasource (specifically `document.MailMerge.DataSource`) and rewrite fields.  If I go that route, where should I execute the macro so that it will get to the data after it's been read from the data source, but before it's been merged with the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not appear to be a way to call arbitrary functions from embedded Word macros, so I went the VBA route.

I added an `AutoOpen` macro to the source document that called `MailMerge.EditDataSource` and then walked through the table to make its changes.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do the data transformation in Microsoft Query? That is, where you currently have:

```
Data Source -> Mail Merge Template
```

create a Microsoft Query that sits between your data source and Word:

```
Data Source -> Microsoft Query -> Mail Merge Template
```

It's been a while since I used Mail Merge in Word but I don't remember being able to exert much control over it...

Comment: I cannot.  I provide a Word document to a third-party program that generates data and performs the merge.  (More precisely, the program sets up a mail merge document with a sample data set and then allows me to edit that document.  I can make any changes I want to the document, but not to most other parts of the process.)